# Optimized hive query needed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

We have two tables containing huge data. And we have to perform inner join between these two tables. Joining condition is based on 3 columns c1,c2,c3.

Need your help in writing an optimized query for the above scenario.
Please refer to the data model below.

```
table1

c1,c2,c3,c4,c5


table2

c1,c2,c3
```

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: I've used "select * from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.c1=t2.c1 and t1.c2=t2.c2 and t1.c3=t2.c3...But it turns out that after the join...the number of records has increased...So I thought inner join hasn't happened properly...or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand [Hortonworks' founder Owen O'Malley](http://www.slideshare.net/oom65/optimize-hivequeriespptx) correctly, you may optimize it by writing

```
SELECT t1.* from table1 t1
JOIN (SELECT table2.* FROM table2) t2
ON (t1.c1=t2.c1 AND t1.c1 = t2.c2 AND t1.c3 = t2.c3)
```

Answer (score 1):

as it seems you are not using any new data from table2 and the logic is "return all rows in table1 that exist in table2".  This is done by using `left semi join`.
The number of records might increase if table2 is not uniqe (same combination of c1 c2 c3 appears more than once).

Answer (score 0):

An inner join will give you all the rows that exist in both table 1 and table 2 as well as any extra combinations that exist with the other columns present in table 2. A left semi join like @dimamah mentioned will give you only those rows that are present in the left table 1.

For the first solution where you should expect more rows

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON (t1.c1=t2.c1 AND t1.c1 = t2.c2 AND t1.c3 = t2.c3)
```

For the second solution where you will get the same number of rows as t1

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT SEMI JOIN table2 t2
ON (t1.c1=t2.c1 AND t1.c1 = t2.c2 AND t1.c3 = t2.c3)
```